# how to pass specific arguments in batch commands during jenkins builds

Tags: windows, jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use Jenkins to automate performance testing with JMeter,
each build is a single JMeter test and I want to increase the number of users(threads) for each Jenkins build if the previous was successful.

I have configured most of the build, with SSH plugin I can restart Tomcat, copy catalina.out, with publishing performance I can open the .jtl file and determine if the build was successful.

What I want is to execute a different batch command for the next build(to increase the number of users(threads) and user id's)
For example:

> jmeter -Jthreads=10 -n -t C:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l C:\TestScripts\Jenkins.jtl
>
> jmeter -Jthreads=20 -n -t C:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l C:\TestScripts\Jenkins.jtl
>
> jmeter -Jthreads=30 -n -t C:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l C:\TestScripts\Jenkins.jtl...

Is there some good jmeter plugin some counter that i can use to increase some variable by 10 each time:

> jmeter -Jthreads=%variable1%...

I have tried  by setting environmental variables and then incrementing that variable by:

> "SET /A thread+=10"

but it doesn't change that variable because jenkins opens its own CMD, a new process :

> ("cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins556482303577128680.bat")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i am creating 20 .jmx files (1.jmx, 2.jmx , 3.jmx ...) each whith a different number of users. and calling them whit this command :

jmeter -n -t C:\TestScripts\%BUILD_NUMBER%.jmx -l C:\TestScripts\%BUILD_NUMBER%.jtl

the first billd will call 1.jmx the second 2.jmx ... 
it isn't the best method but it works for now. I will try your advice over the weekend when i have more time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command to increase `threads` variable by 10:

```
SET /A threads=threads+10
```

Or inside double quotes:

```
SET /A "threads+=10"
```

Comment: i am not sure if this solution will work, because for each build Jenkins calls a different bat file.     for the first build :    cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins4994495302704326582.bat     And for the second :  cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins532038471028093677.bat

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your Jenkins configuration, and which [plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) you have installed and how do you run the test it is quite hard to come up with the best solution.

The only "universal" workaround I can think of is writing the current number of threads into a file in [Jenkins workspace](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) and reading the value of threads from the file on next execution.

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Thread Group
3. Put the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def file = new File(System.getenv('WORKSPACE') + System.getProperty('file.separator') + 'threads.number')

   if (file.exists()) {


       def newThreadNum = (FileUtils.readFileToString(file, 'UTF-8') as int) + 10
       FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, newThreadNum as String)

       def engine = ctx.getEngine()
       def test = org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.FieldUtils.getField(engine.getClass(), 'test', true)
       def testPlanTree = test.get(engine)

       SearchByClass<ThreadGroup> threadGroupSearch = new SearchByClass<>(ThreadGroup.class)
       testPlanTree.traverse(threadGroupSearch)
       def threadGroups = threadGroupSearch.getSearchResults()
       threadGroups.each {
           it.setNumThreads(newThreadNum)
       }
   } else {
       FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, props.get('threads'))
   }
   ```

   The code will write down the current number of threads in all [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) into a file called `threads.number` in Jenkins Workspace and on subsequent runs it reads the value from it, adds 10 and writes it back.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the a solution that works for me, it inst pretty. I created a python script which changes a .CVS fil from which JMeter reads the number of threads and the starting user id. This python script incremets the starting user id by the number of threads in the previous bild and the number of threads by 10

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\mp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\eggs.csv', 'r') 
a,b=file.readlines()[0].split(",")
print(a,b)
b=int(b)
a=int(a)
b=a+b
a=a+10
print(a,b)
f = open("C:\\Users\\mp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\eggs2.csv", "a")
f.write(str(a)+","+str(b))
f.close()
```

I have  python on my pc and a i am calling the script in Jenkins as a windows Bach command

```
C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\rename_write_file.py
```

I am much better in python than Java so I implemented this in Python.
So for each new test,the CSV file from which jmeter reads values is changed.